# php Open_Basedir configuration Apache 2

Tags: apache-2.2, php

We have the following setup:

- /var/www/public <-- DocumentRoot
- /var/www/functions <-- php Functions
- /var/www/config <-- php configurations

Via apache vhost configuration we open the basedir:

```
php_admin_value open_basedir "/var/www/functions/:/var/www/config/"
```

Now if I include a document under functions or config from public, that works as expected.
But if I include a config from within functions that does not.

so:

`/var/www/public/index.php` can include `../functions/test.php`

but

`/var/www/functions/test.php` can't include `../config/config.php`

> open_basedir restriction in effect. File(../config/config.php) is not
>   within the allowed path(s): (/var/www/functions/:/var/www/config/) in
>   /var/www/functions/test.php on line 1067

Any thoughts on this maybe?

Thanks and kind regards

Linus

Additional Info:

If I include with full path it works, as in `include_once("/var/www/config/config.php");` instead of `include_once("../config/config.php");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's something you're writing yourself? Typical PHP use in that case would be:

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . "/bla/foo.php");
```

or

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . "/../config/config.php");
```

Comment: It's for me and a friend, I am not too much of a PHP artist. I just play around with the server config. 
and thanks a lot for your answer, however, just for general information, it's require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . "/../config/config.php"); you where missing one slash ;)

cheers!

Linus

Comment: Ah, indeed. I edited the answer to add the slash.